# Does submersion between compact, connected smooth manifolds imply that they have the same dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Yesterday I did a Differential Topology Exam and I found a question a little strange. I would like to know how I could solve that.

> Let $M^m$ and $N^n$ be compact, connected smooth manifolds, $m\geq n$, and $f:M\longrightarrow N$ be a $C^{\infty}$ submersion. Prove that $f(M) = N$ and that $m = n$.

The first part I did without difficult. I want to know how I can prove that these manifolds have the same dimension.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That does not look right. Projections are submersion and counterexamples to the claim.

Comment: Nope, $M=S^1\times S^1, N=S^1$ and $f(x,y)=x$ gives an obvious counterexample.

Comment: Thanks, friends. I'm not believing about the truth of this question.

Comment: Maybe they wanted to say imersion instead of submersion.

Comment: If we assumed that they wanted to say immersion instead of submersion, I think we are not able to prove that f is surjective. (but I need to think more about it)

Comment: Plausibly, the condition $m \geq n$ was meant to be part of the _conclusion_.

Comment: If it said "immersion" instead, it would be correct (assuming "manifold" doesn't allow boundary).  The conclusion $m=n$ follows from the rank-nullity theorem applied to the tangemt spaces.  Once we know $m=n$, $f$ becomes a submersion, hence an open map.  Since $M$ is assumed compact, $f$ is also closed.  Thus, $f(M)$ must be a component of $N$, so $f$ is surjective.